# Mostrar datos en label de jafafx

Tags: java, mysql, sql, javafx

Hola amigos una pregunta con javafx, estoy probando un alternativa al cargar los datos de una BD en una TableView, ahora quiero cargarlos en un Label, pero siempre que recorro el array list me da el ultimo objeto del arreglo en los labels y por consola me da el arreglo bien

```java
public class ItemController implements Initializable, EmployeesDAO {
    ArrayList <Employees> result = new ArrayList<>();
    @FXML
    private Label LabelName;
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        result = getEmployees();

        for( Employees result : result) {
            String name = result.getName();
            LabelName.setText(name);
        }
    }
}

Este es cada item donde voy a mostrar los datos.
Cabe decir que esto me devuelve bien el string y los datos en la consola con el System.out.println() pero en el label solo me devuelve el ultimo dato del arreglo
```

Comment: En el ciclo estás seteando el texto del label en cada iteración, por eso al final te aparece el último elemento del arreglo, porque el último valor del label es el que seteaste en la última iteración. Creo que lo que quieres es concatenar los resultados, intenta con un StringBuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el `for` estás utilizando el método `setText()` con cada iteración, este método cada vez que lo llamas reemplaza el String que había anteriormente en el Label, es por esto que cuando finaliza el `for`, únicamente ves el último nombre.

Para solucionar el problema tienes que concatenar un String en cada iteración y cuando termine utilizar el método `setText()` con el String que concatenaste.

Así quedaría el método `initialize`

```
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        result = getEmployees();

        String names = "";

        for (Employees result : result) {
            names += result.getName();
            names += "\n"; // Salto de línea
        }

        labelName.setText(names);
    }
```